# Fubini-like theorem for Banach algebra valued functions.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, banach-algebras

I imagine this is standard, but I can't manage to prove it. Any help/hints much appreciated!

Let $B$ be a real, unital, separable Banach algebra and $(X,F,\mu)$ a finite measure space. Suppose that $f,g, f\cdot g:X\to B$ are Bochner integrable, where $f\cdot g$ denotes the pointwise product. Denote by $\mu_f,\mu_g\in\mathrm{Meas}(B)$ the pushforward measures $\mu_f(U)=\mu(f^{-1}(U))$ and similarly $\mu_{(f,g)}\in\mathrm{Meas}(B\times B)$, $\mu_{(f,g)}(U\times V)=\mu\{x\in X:(f(x),g(x))\in U\times V\}.$

Suppose that $$\mu_{(f,g)}=\mu_f\otimes\mu_g$$ (so $f$ and $g$ independent if $\mu$ were a probability measure). Do we then have that

$$\int_Xfd\mu\int_Xgd\mu=\int_Xfgd\mu\;?$$

---

In the case $B=\mathbb R$ and say wlog $f,g\geq 0$, we can approximate with simple functions $f_n=\sum_0^{n^2}\frac{k}{n}\chi_{f^{-1}[k/n,(k+1)/n)}$ and $g_n$ similarly. It is then easy to show that $\int f_ng_n=\int f_n\int g_n$ and fiddling with MCT & DCT completes the proof. I'm having trouble extending this type of reasoning to general Banach algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same argument works. Suppose first that $f$ and $g$ are simple, i.e.
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^n\chi_{A_i}a_i,\quad g=\sum_{j=1}^m\chi_{B_j}b_j,$$
and so
$$f\cdot g=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\chi_{A_i\cap B_j}a_i\cdot b_j$$
which is also simple. Taking Bochner integrals we find
$$\int_Xf\cdot gd\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\mu(A_i\cap B_j)a_i\cdot b_j,\\
\left(\int_Xfd\mu\right)\cdot\left(\int_Xgd\mu\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)a_i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\mu(B_j)b_j\right)$$
and so clearly the result will follow if we have $\mu(A_i\cap B_j)=\mu(A_i)\mu(B_j)$ for all $i,j$. But $A_i=f^{-1}\{a_i\}$ and $B_j=g^{-1}\{b_j\}$, and so
$$\mu(A_i\cap B_j)=\mu_{(f,g)}(\{a_i\}\times\{b_j\})=\mu_f\{a_i\}\mu_g\{b_j\}=\mu(A_i)\mu(B_j).$$

For the general case, recall that for separable spaces measurable functions are strongly measurably. Since $f$ is $\sigma(f)$-measurable, $f$ is $\sigma(f)$-strongly measurable, thus Bochner integrable with respect to $(X,\sigma(f),\mu|_{\sigma(f)})$. Hence there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of $\sigma(f)$-measurable simple functions such that $\int_X\|f_n-f\|d\mu\to0)$. By passing to a subsequence, we may assume $\|f_n-f\|\to0$ almost everywhere, and by multiplying by $\chi_{\{x\in X:\|f_n(x)\|\le2\|f(x)\|\}}$ we may assume $\|f_n\|\le2\|f\|$. Define $\{g_n\}$ similarly.

Observe that $\mu_{(f_n,g_n)}=\mu_{f_n}\otimes\mu_{g_n}$ for each $n$, $f_n\cdot g_n\to f\cdot g$ almost everywhere (by continuity of multiplication), and $\|f_n\cdot g_n\|\le\|f_n\|\|g_n\|\le4\|f\|\|g\|$. We want to be able to conclude
\begin{align*}
\int_Xf\cdot gd\mu &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\cdot g_nd\mu\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_Xf_nd\mu\right)\cdot\left(\int_Xg_nd\mu\right)\\
&=\left(\int_Xfd\mu\right)\cdot\left(\int_Xgd\mu\right).
\end{align*}
The only line we need to justify is the first, and this will follow from the dominated convergence theorem if we can show that $\|f\|\|g\|$ is integrable. However, we also have that $\mu_{(\|f\|,\|g\|)}=\mu_{\|f\|}\otimes\mu_{\|g\|}$, and so by the real case we have
$$\int_X\|f\|\|g\|d\mu=\left(\int_X\|f\|d\mu)\right)\left(\int_X\|g\|d\mu\right)<\infty,$$
completing the proof.

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for this. When you write $\int f_n\cdot g_n = \int f_n\cdot\int g_n$, you seem to be assuming that $\mu_{(f_n,g_n)}=\mu_{f_n}\otimes\mu_{(g_n)}$. Why must there exist such a choice of $f_n, g_n$ approximating $f$ and $g$?

Comment: That's a good point. Let me edit in a little more detail.

Comment: Edited. I ended up using the fact that $B$ is separable, which is equivalent to the fact that all measurable functions are strongly measurable. This is somewhat surprising to me, since the whole point of specifying that Bochner integrable functions are strongly measurable is to get around problems that require separability, so one would expect the result to hold in the non-separable case, but perhaps not.

Comment: An observation: $f$ is $\sigma(f)$-measurable and therefore Bochner integrable if we restrict the $\sigma$-algebra. Namely, $f:(X,\sigma(f),\mu)\to B$ is still Bochner integrable (and similarly for $g$ with the sigma algebra $\sigma(g)$). Then there exist simple functions $f_n$ which are $\sigma(f)$-measurable and similarly $g_n$. Then we do indeed have $\mu_{f_n}\otimes\mu_{g_n}=\mu_{(f_n, g_n)}$, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure the $f_n$ you propose using preimages of balls in $B$ actually converge pointwise. What's concerning me is that although those balls cover $B$, they don't partition it: they could have many nontrivial intersections.

Comment: I had noticed that, but you need the separability of $B$ to be able to deduce $f$ is Bochner integrable with respect to $\sigma(f)$. I was trying to avoid that by more or less showing directly that measurable functions are strongly measurable on a separable space, but obviously I was not careful enough in my argument :-)